# How to run script that uses NestJs service

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I'm trying to run a script outside the `src` folder that uses a nest stand-alone application. I was able to fix most of the import errors by adding this to the `tsconfig.json`:

```
"ts-node": {
    "require": ["tsconfig-paths/register"]
  }
```

But I'm still getting this error:

```
/Users/xxx/Documents/GitHub/project-api/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:859
    return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes, diagnostics);
           ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/auth/constants.ts:17:71 - error TS2552: Cannot find name 'UTCString'. Did you mean 'String'?

17 export const SIGN_MESSAGE_TEMPLATE = (address: string, utcTimeString: UTCString) =>
                                                                         ~~~~~~~~~

  /Users/xxx/Documents/GitHub/project-api/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es5.d.ts:544:13
    544 declare var String: StringConstructor;
                    ~~~~~~
    'String' is declared here.

    at createTSError (/Users/xxx/Documents/GitHub/project-api/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:859:12)
    at reportTSError (/Users/xxx/Documents/GitHub/project-api/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:863:19)
    at getOutput (/Users/xxx/Documents/GitHub/project-api/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1077:36)
    at Object.compile (/Users/xxx/Documents/GitHub/project-api/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1433:41)
    at Module.m._compile (/Users/xxx/Documents/GitHub/project-api/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1617:30)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (/Users/xxx/Documents/GitHub/project-api/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1621:12)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19) {
  diagnosticCodes: [ 2552 ]
}
```

My script has this format:

```
import { TransactionsService } from '../../../src/transactions/transactions.service';
import { AppModule } from '../../../src/app.module';    

const prisma = new PrismaClient();
    
  async function main() {
     const app = await NestFactory.createApplicationContext(AppModule);
      const transactionService = app.get(TransactionsService);
    
     //...
    
     await app.close();
    }
    
    main()
      .catch(async (e) => {
        console.error(e);
        process.exit(1);
      })
      .finally(async () => {
        await prisma.$disconnect();
      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem, I just needed to add the "files" to the `tsconfig.json` file.

```
"ts-node": {
        "require": ["tsconfig-paths/register"]
        "files": true
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [standalone mode](https://docs.nestjs.com/standalone-applications) along with `--entryFile` option from Nest's CLI: `npx nest start --entryFile script`. That ends up using the same typescript config as your main app but you can play with the CLI options to change that. Read the docs: https://docs.nestjs.com/cli/usages#nest-start

Comment: I'm getting this error
```
 Error  Cannot find module '/Users/xxx/Documents/GitHub/project-api/dist/scripts/hydrate-db/transactions/index.ts'
Require stack:
- /Users/xxx/Documents/GitHub/project-api/node_modules/@nestjs/cli/actions/start.action.js
- /Users/xxx/Documents/GitHub/project-api/node_modules/@nestjs/cli/actions/index.js
- /Users/xxx/Documents/GitHub/project-api/node_modules/@nestjs/cli/commands/command.loader.js
-/Users/xxx/Documents/GitHub/project-api/node_modules/@nestjs/cli/commands/index.js
-/Users/xxx/Documents/GitHub/project-api/node_modules/@nestjs/cli/bin/nest.js
```